# Getting 500 error when trying to query my db with JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud-repository

Here is the error I get:

```
Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

I have a basic site that allows you to create a "song" that contains a title, artist and rating. You can edit/delete the songs and the app will display all the songs on the main page. It has a function to order the songs by their rating in descending order which works and a feature to search which only half works.

I don't understand what's wrong because it works when I use the feature to search the first time, then on the second search it always throws this error.

Digging a little deeper I think these error lines are relevant:

```
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy112.findByArtistContaining(Unknown Source)
    at com.cshannon.lookify.services.SongService.findByArtist(SongService.java:50)
    at com.cshannon.lookify.controllers.MainController.search(MainController.java:105)
```

I can't understand why it thinks the string I am entering is an unkown source when it works the first time I do it without errors. I have tried changing the route from a Get to a Post and that doesn't make a difference.

The controller code:

```js
@GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(
            Model model,
            @RequestParam(value="search") String search
            ) {
        
        if (search.isEmpty()) {
            return "redirect:/dashboard";
        }
        
        ArrayList<Song> songs = ss.findByArtist(search);
        model.addAttribute("songs", songs);
        
        return "search.jsp";
        
    }
```

The service:

```js
// Find by artist
    public ArrayList<Song> findByArtist(String search) {
        
        return (ArrayList<Song>) sr.findByArtistContaining(search);
        
    }
```

The repository:

```js
ArrayList<Song> findByArtistContaining(String search);
```

And if it helps here is the form I am using to get the string from the user:

```
<form action="/search" class="d-flex">
    <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search Artists" class="btn btn-outline-success"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix for both security issue [CVE-2022-22968](https://tanzu.vmware.com/security/cve-2022-22968) and this bug, you can use spring-boot version 2.5.13

Comment: Thanks, currently just using it for a class I am in but in an actual deployed app I will definitely make sure to keep an eye out. Any idea what causes the bug in the first place?

Comment: Apparently it is a bug in hibernate (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2472) that happens with  repository methods with keywords such as LIKE or CONTAINING...

Answer (score 1):

Wow I figured out the issue. I don't know the low level explanation for this but for some reason it's an error with Spring Boot 2.6.6 and changing it to 2.6.3 in the dependencies fixed it.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Using version 2.6.7 also has this issue. I went through the various versions and it seems that this issues was broken between 2.6.4 and 2.6.5. However based on the post by Eva, it is definitely a hibernate change that that issue leads you down the best path.